# Convert ISO3 country code to whole country name, Android

Tags: java, android, locale, iso

I need to convert country iso3 code for example FRA to France is it possible? I tried with:
`Locale locale = new Locale("FRA") or Locale locale = new Locale("","FRA")
locale.getDisplayCountry()`
but return empty String.

Answer (score 1):

2nd parameter of Locale constructor needs a ISO2 code, not ISO3. You need to first map ISO3 to ISO2 and then get country name.

This possibly the worst case solution, I don't know any better solution, but its works.

```
String[] languages = Locale.getISOLanguages();
Map<String, Locale> localeMap = new HashMap<String, Locale>(languages.length);
for (String language : languages) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    localeMap.put(locale.getISO3Language(), locale);
}
Locale locale = new Locale("",localeMap("FRA"));
Log.e("loc",""+locale.getDisplayCountry());
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin you can do below:

```
object CountryCodeConverter {
    private val countryCodes: MutableList<CountryCode>

    fun iso3CountryCodeToIso2CountryCode(iso3CountryCode: String?): String? {
        return countryCodes.find { it.iso3CountryCode == iso3CountryCode }?.locale?.country
    }
    
    fun getCountry(iso3CountryCode: String?): String? {
        return countryCodes.find { it.iso3CountryCode == iso3CountryCode }?.locale?.displayCountry
    }

    init {
        countryCodes = ArrayList()
        countryCodes.addAll(Locale.getISOCountries().map {country->
            val locale = Locale("", country)
            CountryCode(
                locale.isO3Country.toUpperCase(),
                locale
            )
        })
    }
}

data class CountryCode (
    val iso3CountryCode: String,
    val locale: Locale
)
```